# How to obtain all image links from a Reddit page's posts using requests in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Here is the code I am working with using python requests and the variable page passed in is "http://www.reddit.com/r/okbuddyretard/top/?t=day". Not sure what I am doing wrong where I am not able to read the HTML and pull all of the images from posts.

```py
def return_image_links(page):
    page = requests.get(page, headers = headers)
    if page.status_code == 200:
        page.html.render(sleep =5,timeout = 8) # Not sure if I am doing this right either
        urls = page.html.xpath("a[ends-with(@src, '.jpg')]") #This is the part I can't figure out
        print(urls)
        image_urls = []
        for url in urls:
            if is_image(url):
                image_urls.append(url)                      
            else:
                image_urls.extend(get_imgur_gallery_links(url))
        return image_urls 
    else:
        print('Bad response from reddit server.')
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `urls = page.html.xpath("a[ends-with(@src, '.jpg')]")` is simply wrong, you seem to be trying to use methods which are present under the [lxml nodule](https://lxml.de/installation.html#building-lxml-from-dev-sources), while using names (`html.xpath`) that do not live under the class [requests.Response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response).

The following is an example which uses `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to parse the html and access to the images :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import sys


def return_image_links(url, headers):
    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    if page.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")
        img_tags = soup.select('img[alt="Post image"]')

        image_urls = []
        for img_tag in img_tags:
           image_urls.append(img_tag['src'])
        return image_urls
    else:
        print('Bad response from reddit server.')
        sys.exit()


url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/okbuddyretard/top/?t=day"
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0'}
imgs = return_image_links(url, headers)

print(*imgs, sep='\n')
```